# Error using bquote() for axis labelling

Tags: r

I'm experiencing a strange error when using the function `bquote` for axis labeling. The error is only occurring when applying the label (the greek symbol "mu") to the y-axis:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
plot(y~x, df, t="l", xlab=bquote(.("Size [")*mu*m*.("]"))) # works
plot(y~x, df, t="l", ylab=bquote(.("Size [")*mu*m*.("]"))) # doesn't work
# Error in plot.default(1:10, 1:10, ylab = "Size [" * mu * m * "]", xlab = quote("x"),  : object 'mu' not found
```

I know I could use `expression` as an alternative in this case, but I'm trying to understand the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to subtleties of evaluation rules and the specifics of the implementation of this plotting function.

Note that this does not occur when not using the formula interface

```
plot(df$x,df$y, type="l", ylab=bquote(.("Size [")*mu*m*.("]"))) #works as you expect
```

To see what is happening, examine the source

```
getAnywhere("plot.formula")
```

and you'll see the equivalent of this simplified example

```
plotex<-function(x,y,type="l",ylab,...) {
  m=match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  dots <- lapply(m$..., eval)
  dots$xlab <- enquote(dots$xlab)
  do.call(plot,c(list(x=x,y=y,type=type,ylab=ylab),dots))
}
```

The `xlab` argument is in `...` and protected against evaluation with an explicit `enquote`. The `ylab` is a named parameter and its evaluation is forced by inclusion in the `list` provided to `do.call`.